# Editar Imagem no Mysql + PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá gente primeira pergunta minha aqui no site desculpe se eu acabar fazendo algo errado.
Minha duvida é o seguinte, quando eu vou fazer a alteração dos dados de um produto sempre tenho que colocar a foto no campo input porque se eu não colocar não o meu código acaba alterando o nome no banco de dados deixando ele vazio, como faço para alterar os dados do formulário sem precisar sempre carregar a imagem?

Segue o código de update

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("seguranca.php");
include_once("conexao.php");



if(isset($_FILES['imagem']))
   {
    date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão
    $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['imagem']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
    $new_name = date("Y.m.d-H.i.s") . $ext; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
    $dir = '../imagens/'; //Diretório para uploads

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo

   }

$id                 = $_POST["id"];
$nome               = $_POST["nome"];
$preco              = $_POST["preco"];
$divide             = $_POST["divide"];
$tamanho            = $_POST["tamanho"];
$marca_id           = $_POST["marca_id"];
$cor_id             = $_POST["cor_id"];
$situacao_id        = $_POST["situacao_id"];
$cate_id            = $_POST["cate_id"];
$imagem             = $new_name;

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE produtos set nome ='$nome', preco = '$preco', divide = '$divide', tamanho = '$tamanho', marca_id = '$marca_id', cor_id = '$cor_id', situacao_id = '$situacao_id', cate_id = '$cate_id', foto = '$imagem' WHERE id='$id'");?>
```

O do html esta assim

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagem:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="imagem" placeholder="" value="">
      </div>
      </div>
```

Obrigado e se tiver algo errado na minha pergunta me falem novato aqui.

Comment: Faz um if. Se $_files for vazio execute outra query de update sem a parte que faça essa atualização da imagem. Ou quando selecionar as informações que vai editar carregue um campo input separado trazendo o nome do arquivo. Depois envia esse nome pro banco. Geralmente uso outra alternativa com JavaScript.

Comment: Obrigado @WillianCoqueiro Irei fazer isso, sou novo nesta área, um pouco leigo ainda.

Comment: Deu pra entender né. Se $imagem for vazio executa outra query sem atualizar o nome dela lá no banco.

Comment: Deu sim amigo, vou fazer o If aqui e ja retorno falando o resultado

Comment: Responda ela é coloque solução ou eu respondo e coloque solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir fazer oque eu queria com a ajuda do @Willian Coqueiro segue o código.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("seguranca.php");
include_once("conexao.php");

$id                 = $_POST["id"];
$nome               = $_POST["nome"];
$preco              = $_POST["preco"];
$divide             = $_POST["divide"];
$tamanho            = $_POST["tamanho"];
$marca_id           = $_POST["marca_id"];
$cor_id             = $_POST["cor_id"];
$situacao_id        = $_POST["situacao_id"];
$cate_id            = $_POST["cate_id"];
$arquivo            = $_FILES['imagem']['name'];

if($arquivo == ""){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE produtos set nome ='$nome', preco = '$preco', divide = '$divide', tamanho = '$tamanho', marca_id = '$marca_id', cor_id = '$cor_id', situacao_id = '$situacao_id', cate_id = '$cate_id' WHERE id='$id'");
}else{


 if(isset($_FILES['imagem']))
   {
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
      $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão
    $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['imagem']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
    $new_name = $resultado['foto']; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
    $dir = '../imagens/'; //Diretório para uploads

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name); //Fazer upload do arquivo

   }

$imagem             = $new_name;

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE produtos set nome ='$nome', preco = '$preco', divide = '$divide', tamanho = '$tamanho', marca_id = '$marca_id', cor_id = '$cor_id', situacao_id = '$situacao_id', cate_id = '$cate_id', foto = '$imagem' WHERE id='$id'");}
?>
```